# How to determine estimated block or transaction time

Tags: transactions, wallet, currencies

I would like to know if there is any possible way to determine the estimated block time for a special cryptocurrency at the present time so I can estimate the transaction time it takes to send coins from one to another wallet.

Any help in this matter?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without knowing your blockchain's rules - it could literally be anything.

Answer (score 0):

The target block time is usually hard coded. Block time is a function of the current difficulty and the current network hash rate. In Bitcoin, the target hash rate is ten minutes and the difficulty is regularly adjusted to maintain this block time on average.

Whether or not a particular transaction will be included in a particular block is speculative since it is up to miners to include the transaction, however, it is generally considered that transactions with relatively higher fees are more likely to be included.